# How to download xml file and save in local iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a magazine application i want that it load file from server and store it in application when application starts first time only and then use that locally file to save  time  i am getting data which is located on server it takes alot time

```
     NSURL*myurl=url; 

      myurl = [myurl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
     myurl = [myurl stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]; 



     NSURL*urlloaded= [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:myurl];

    //NSURL*url= [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/RowOne.xml"];

    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlloaded];
```

//Initialize the delegate.

```
     RowTwoParser *parser = [[RowTwoParser alloc] initXMLParser];
```

//Set delegate

```
     [xmlParser setDelegate:parser];   
    BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

  if(success)

  NSLog(@"No Errors");

   else

   NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!");
```

Comment: Instead of saving your xml file.I would suggest to save your data.What I mean is you might have extracted your data in dictionary or array , so save that dictionary or array in NSUserDefults and use it everytime .it will reduce your work effort of doing xml parsing again and again.

Comment: yes  i have saved that data in array so how may use that without parsing again and again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is:-

Suppose you have parsed  your xml and stored data in array say '`dataArray`'

Now you have to save your `dataArray` in `NSUserDefaults`

```
NSUserDefaults *pref1=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[pref1 setObject:dataArray forKey:@"parseData"];    
[pref1 synchronize];
```

Whenever you have to use this data you can extract it like:-

```
NSUserDefaults *pref1=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *dataArray=[pref1 objectForKey:@"parseData"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can download the initial data i.e the XML file by using something like this

```
- (void)downloadInitialData {
    NSUserDefaults* userDefaults =  [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([userDefaults boolForKey:@"DATA_DOWNLOAD_KEY"] == NO) {
        [self showWaitViewWithText:@"Downloading Data..."];
        [self fetchDataFromServer];
    }
}



- (void)fetchDataFromServer {

    //Call to server to downlaod data
    //When Data is successfully downloaded

    //Stop loading when data save completes
    [self stopLoading];

    //Update USerDefaults
    NSUserDefaults* userDefaults =  [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"DATA_DOWNLOAD_KEY"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
}
```

You can make call to `[self downloadInitialData];` which will ensure that Data is downloaded only once when the application starts . You will have to fix it according to your requirements to download data by resetting the **@"DATA_DOWNLOAD_KEY"** key.

Comment: @Jogi You can edit your question and add additional information to show code have you used.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Apples own [SeismicXML](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SeismicXML/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007323-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) example - source code available.

Comment: I have checked that but it has a lot of modifications to do